# How can I generate a multiplication table with headers as a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I want to create a function that will generate a multiplication table with a header row and a header column.

The function must take 3 arguments:

- `col` - (integer) start value for numbers in columns
- `row` - (integer) start value for numbers in rows
- `size` - (integer) size of the table

calling `table(1,3,4)` must give this result:

```
[ 
    [null, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [3, 3, 6, 9, 12], 
    [4, 4, 8, 12, 16], 
    [5, 5, 10, 15, 20], 
    [6, 6, 12, 18, 24] 
]
```

Note that:

- Numbers in the header row begin at `1` (the first argument)
- Numbers down the first column begin at `3` (the second argument)
- The table contains `4` (the third argument) non-header rows and columns, for a total size of `5` rows and columns.

So far, I have this code (below), but how can I put the values inside?

```
let table = new Array(++size);
    
for(let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  table[i] = new Array(size);
}
```

There are more requirements, but I don't know how to make them happen.

- `table[0]` describes row with columns headings
- `table[0][0]` is always `null` - this will correspond to an empty top-left cell of the table.
- `table[i][0]` describes row heading (where `i` is any index)
- `table[0][j]` describes column heading (where `j` is any index)
- `table[0][1]` is equal to `col`
- `table[1][0]` is equal to `row`
- `table[i][j]` is equal to the product of two numbers: `table[i][0]` and `table[0][j]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
function table(col_start, row_start, size){
    let table = new Array(size+1);

    for(let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        table[i] = new Array(size+1);
    }
    
    table[0][0]=null

    for(let i = 1; i < size+1; i++) {
        table[0][i] = col_start+i-1
    }

    for(let i = 1; i < size+1; i++) {
        table[i][0] = row_start+i-1
    }

    for(let i = 1; i < size+1; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j < size+1; j++) {
            table[i][j] = table[0][j]*table[i][0]
        }
    }
    return table
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all - JavaScript doesn't provide multidimensional arrays. If you want to make one - here's how you do it (well it would not be a multidimensional array but you can make it work like it).

```
function multiDimensional(r,c){  // r = number of rows, c = columns
    const arr = Array.from({length : 5}, ()=>[]); //creates an array with 5 empty arrays in it.
    let count = 0;

    while(count !== r){    //count is index of the empty arrays inside the array.
        for(let i = 0; i < r*c; i++){    // r*c is size of array.
            arr[count].push(i);      //pushing values inside subarrays. e.g. arr[0].push(0)
           
            if(i !== 0 && (i+1) % 5 === 0){  //incrementing count after every 5 loop repetitions
              count++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(arr[1][0]) // now u can use arr[a][b] notation.
    return arr;
}

multiDimensional(5,5);
```

the desired table looks this (don't forget that array starts from 0, so row 1 is actually row 0, same for column) -

```
arr = [
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  // place value = 00, 01, 02, 03, 04  or simply r0c0, r0c1 etc
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    // place value = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]   // place value = 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]   // place value = 30, 31, 32, 33, 34
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]    // place value = 40, 41, 42, 43 44
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
It`s good solution but it`s a bit hard to understand when u are a newbie

Comment: No problem man. Come later when you feel you can understand it. It will be understandable then.